# With a git hook, how do I force or check user identity?

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

I'm trying to setup a gitolite server. One problem that I find annoying in git is the username is not checked when committing code.

This can lead to a possible "identity phishing" where user1 can commit some bogus code and set user2 as username. Then we'll blame user2.

I'm looking for a way to check or force the username to be consistent with the committer's identity.

Comment: If you use ssh there's no user phishing possible

Comment: Git has use cases when one user legitimately commits work authored by other users. Say you push a commit that I rebase and push onto my topic branch. How would you want to handle that situation?

Comment: @CharlesB Yes if the users has both valid ssh access but i can change my git username and make my push as another user name

Comment: @GregBacon good point ... Not sure how to handle that ! So basically what you're saying is that this is stupid and that git relies on the honesty of the developers and that i have to trust them ?

Answer (score 4):

You can sign your commits using: `git commit -S` (only available since git 1.7.9)

You can then use a server-side git hook to refuse any unsigned commit.

Source: http://phreaknerd.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/signing-git-commits-with-your-gpg-key/

Comment: [This link](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/GPG-signing-for-git-commit-td2582986.html) has a discussion on why signing each commit is "stupid". Worth a read.

Comment: counter-example: "[a git horror story](http://mikegerwitz.com/papers/git-horror-story)" by [Mike Gerwitz](http://mikegerwitz.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

With a git hook, you get the ref which is updated.
You can check the whole commits tree being pushed and thus get the commiter name & email (though if it's not signed, you won't ever be sure of it).

Gitolite uses env variables to store various informations, you can take them to get the name of the person being connected, and do your verification.

Comment: it seems that it's a good start to you have some kind of script example for that ?